# Elementary Measure theory problem, and graduate school inquiry .

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, soft-question

I actually have one question, and one concern.

Let $X$ be a metric space and let $\mu$ be a measure in $B(X)$. Prove that $\mu^*(E)=$inf  $\mu(U)$,  where $U$ is open and $E\subset(U)$ defines a metric outer measure.

I would like some sort of hint. Not the answer.

I know that I need to show for $d(E,F)>0$ $\mu^*(E ∪ F) = \mu^∗(E) + \mu^∗(F).$

My only idea is that if $E \in B(X)$, then $X-E \in B(X),$ but I do not know if this helps.

This seems like a very trivial problem and I cannot figure it out. I am a first year graduate student, and I am starting to doubt whether or not I should be in graduate school. I figured that I would struggle, but not like this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get started, let us find two open sets $U,V$ where $E \subset U$, $F \subset V$, $U \cap V = \emptyset$, and ideally so that $U,V$ are "good approximations" to $E,F$ in some sense. To do that, let $d(E,F)=a>0$. Let $r \in (0,a/2]$. Then consider $U=\bigcup_{x \in E} B(x,r)$ and $V=\bigcup_{x \in F} B(x,r)$.

As for your side inquiry, that is frankly a bit off-topic here, but let me say that if you haven't at least seen the theory of the Lebesgue measure on the real line (I hadn't, when I was a first year), diving right into measure theory on metric spaces is going to be pretty tough. So stick it out. Lots of people share your doubt early on and ultimately get through it.

Comment: Thank you. I will play with this. Although, wouldn't we take $x\in E$ and $y \in F$, where $x \neq y$?

Comment: @Krampus You could call it $y$ instead; the variable is bound inside the union, so it doesn't really matter what we call it. (Computer scientists call this "local scope".)